# How to create a floating bar graph that identifies similar events with a sequence of start and end dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, timeline, floating

I am trying to create the following image using ggplot2. The code I have attempted isn't working at all, so I'd be happy with any suggestions with a fresh approach.

```
site <- c("LA", "LA", "LA", "WR", "WR", "WR", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS")
startdate <- as.Date(c('1601-01-01', '1836-01-01','1672-01-01','1912-01-01','1946-01-01',
                       '1835-01-01','1454-01-01','1672-01-01','1877-01-01','1978-01-01'))
enddate <-as.Date(c('1605-01-01','1841-01-01','1676-01-01','1918-01-01','1951-01-01',
                    '1839-01-01','1459-01-01','1676-01-01','1881-01-01','1983-01-01'))

data.frame <-data.frame(site, startdate, enddate)
```

[image: Floating Bar Graph]

Comment: What code have you tried?  Were you using `geom_segment`?

Comment: Following the suggestion from aosmith: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(data.frame) + geom_segment(aes(x=startdate, xend=enddate, y=site, yend=site), lwd=15)`

Comment: Thank you Mr.Flick, it works. I think I made it too complicated and was trying geom_rect.

Answer (score 1):

Because your time range is large, it is interesting to use an interactive plot, where you can zoom in. To that end you could use the package `vistime`. After installing the package, run the following code:

```
# your code
site <- c("LA", "LA", "LA", "WR", "WR", "WR", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS")
startdate <- as.Date(c('1601-01-01', '1836-01-01','1672-01-01','1912-01-01','1946-01-01', '1835-01-01','1454-01-01','1672-01-01','1877-01-01','1978-01-01'))
enddate <-as.Date(c('1605-01-01','1841-01-01','1676-01-01','1918-01-01','1951-01-01', '1839-01-01','1459-01-01','1676-01-01','1881-01-01','1983-01-01'))
data.frame <-data.frame(site, startdate, enddate)

# new code
library(vistime)
vistime(data = data.frame, events = "site" ,start="startdate", end = "enddate")
```

it takes the events (the site) with startdate and enddate and plots it.
You may zoom in using the mouse, other options are in the buttons at the top-right.